# Why CSS is not taking effect on my simple HTML page?

Tags: html, css

The `CSS` file is not able to take effect in the `HTML` files. What could be the reason if I ask please?

This is the `HTML` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\gadhavi\Desktop\Header\header.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div class="header">

       </div>
           <div class="inner_header">
           <div class="logo_container">
               <h1>MY<span>APP</span></h1>
           </div>
        </div>

           <ul class="navigation">
               <a><li>Home</li></a>
               <a><li>About</li></a>
               <a><li>Portfolio</li></a>
               <a><li>Contact</li></a>
           </ul>

       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Am I making mistake to include `CSS` file?

Comment: can you share the project folder structure?

Comment: C:\Users\gadhavi\Desktop\Header\header.html

Comment: C:\Users\gadhavi\Desktop\Header\header.css

Comment: just you need put the name css file: `href="header.css"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the path where your css is being called from.

Replace this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\gadhavi\code\hussain\src\header.css">
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css">
```